# set command arguments type in minecraft plugin (Java)

Tags: java, plugins, minecraft

I want to send arguments feedback to player like this:
[Minecraft Feedback Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OBv5K.png)

```
import org.bukkit.command.Command;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandExecutor;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandSender;

public class ctrl implements CommandExecutor {
    public void ctrl(){

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command command, String label, String[] args) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

What I have to do something to send feedback to player?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the TabCompleter interface is what you're looking for.
https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/spigot/org/bukkit/command/TabCompleter.html

To use it, you will need to implement it in one of your classes. You can implement it in your `ctrl` class if you want. The `onTabComplete` method will return a list of suggestions in a `List<String>`.

```java
    @Override
    public List<String> onTabComplete(CommandSender sender, Command command, String alias, String[] args) {
        List<String> completions = new ArrayList<>();
        
        // Use "args" to know exactly what the player has already typed so far 
        // Put the suggestions that you want to show the player into "completions".

        return completions;
    }
```

In the `onEnable` method in your main class, you need to register the `ctrl` class (or a different class if you want) as the tab completer associated with the command you want.

```java
    @Override
    public void onEnable() {
       this.getCommand("example").setTabCompleter(new ctrl());
    }
```

[This post](https://www.spigotmc.org/threads/tab-complete.160308/#post-1703393) shows a way to alphabetically determine potential autocompletions.

Comment: To get the command and tab completer in one single class and without having to manually register it, you can use [TabExecutor](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/spigot/org/bukkit/command/TabExecutor.html). It works the same as CommandExecutor but adds the onTabComplete method.